# pickadate.js navigation events

Tags: javascript, jquery, pickadate

When using pickadate.js is there any event to listen to when the next/previous month buttons are clicked?

I have read through the api and tried to find a response or similar question but I'm coming up short.

I understand this might not be the best way to go about the problem so I appreciate any other approaches.

The reason I am adding styling this way, is I want to select multiple specific dates to be highlighted. I understand there is a datepicker.set('highlight,.. option, however it is my understanding that it only supports one selection at a time.

I was manually applying the styling changes to the correct dates through jquery on render, however switching months loses all styling and even any handle to el(s), but doesn't appear to fire any of the events you can tap in to.

Comment: please show us the code you are having trouble with

Comment: the code is pickadate.js lib. I can post some specific code when I get back in 3 days. However I'm just looking for functionality in the library, to hook in to forward/backward month events